# Setting conditions on MULTIPLE Components in Wix

Tags: wix, components, conditional-statements, windows-installer

I would like to set a condition on multiple components but do not wish to reuse the condition over and over per each component but instead group the components together under a condition **that's not an launch entry condition**  like Fragment is.

Ideas of what to use? ComponentGroup for instance was not a valid child of Directory and I don't really know what to use to group the first two components below with one condition.

PS. Fragment, DirectoryRef and Directory I'm not allowed to change.

I would like something like this:

```
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="blbalba">
         <Directory Id="bin" Name="bin">
          
           **<Condition>**
            <my condition>    
             <Component Id="id1.dll" Guid="{a guid}">
                <File Id="id2.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="mysource.dll" />
             </Component>
            
            <Component Id="id3.dll" Guid="{another guid}">
                <File Id="id3.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="anothermysource.dll" />
            </Component>
           **</Condition>**

            <Component> **bla bla bla no condition here**
            </Component>

        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may group your components into a **Feature** and define single condition for this feature.

Otherwise, you must define each condition individually for each **Component**.

The **Condition** can be only set on these elements: *Component, Control, Feature, Fragment, PermissionEx, Product*.

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html

Comment: I can't add Feature under Directory or DirectoryRef as Feature is not a valid child element of these two.
Nor can I put DirectoryRef under Feature.

Comment: You define Components under a Directory. The Feature is set on different level and you assign components to a Feature as those components already have directories specified.

Comment: Could you show an example, I've read that condition link many times but it doesn't make it clear to me. 

Where do I put the Feature? Also the above code in my example is all under a Fragment. No matter where I put the Feature it says invalid child/parent